# Ubuntu 18.04.1 System Settings Won't Launch!

Tags: 18.04, settings

Having an issue with settings after updating today. I've tried to launch from terminal, but I just get bus error (core dumped). Also tried

```
sudo apt remove gnome-control-center
sudo autoremove
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Still no luck if anyone has any tips it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry to hear that but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA graphics I had to install proprietary nvidia-driver-430.40 to make the System Settings "gnome-control-center" work.

and added repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and ran

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The problem was solved.

If does not work for you. To remove the PPAs run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

[Modified from here.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391819)

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed to make my settings work. interestingly.